# Build independant admin router with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've built an app with its specific router. Now I want to improve my app by coding an admin interface. The thing is, I have components (Navbar and Footer) that surround my routes (see code below). 
So if I simply create an admin interface and nest it inside my existing router, my app's navbar and footer will appear on the admin pages.

I would like to code my admin interface with its own navbar and components.

Is there a way to do so ?

AppRouter.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import LandingPage from '../ui/landing-page/LandingPage';
import App from '../ui/App';
import NotFoundPage from '../ui/NotFoundPage';
import NavBar from '../ui/NavBar';
import Footer from '../ui/Footer';
import FaqPage from '../ui/FaqPage';
import PrivacyPage from'../ui/PrivacyPage';
import LegalNoticePage from '../ui/LegalNoticePage';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/meals" component={App}/>
        <Route exact path="/faq" component={FaqPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/privacy" component={PrivacyPage}/>
        <Route exact path="/legal_notice" component={LegalNoticePage}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<NavBar />` isn't surrounding your `<Router>`, it's surrounding your routes. Since you can nest Routers, you could have a `<Route>` which matches all `path="/admin"` and then within that put the admin-only NavBar.

You can read more about nested routes [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/).

Here's a code example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Admin = ({ match }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <h1>admin bar</h1>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/1`} render={() => <h2>one</h2>} />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/2`} render={() => <h2>two</h2>} />
  </React.Fragment>
);

const Other = ({ match }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <h1>other bar</h1>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/2`} render={() => <h2>one</h2>} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/2`} render={() => <h2>two</h2>} />
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And accompanying [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/460ny92jw).

Comment: thank you @Colin that's very interesting. However, I want My admin interface to have its own admin-navbar, but without rending the app's navbar on any admin route. Tell me if I'm wrong, but nested routes, the way they are presented on the link you provided, do not allow for an admin-only navbar, without rendering the app's navbar as well.

Comment: They do, you'd just have two separate top-level Routes.